# Can't unlock bootloader after `fastboot oem lock` on Xiaomi

Tags: fastboot, xiaomi, bootloader-lock

I have owned a Xiaomi Redmi 9 for a while now and I have a problem. A short time ago, I locked the phone's bootloader to make it like new, and it was a serious mistake. I bought a new mobile and thought about using the old one as a backup. This endorsement should have:

- Bootloader unlocked
- Root activated

I must add that that device had a Mi account that belonged to me and I deleted it. After doing that and relocking the bootloader using the precious command of `fastboot oem unlock`, the next message appears:

```
FAILED (remote: Unlock failed...return to fastboot in 3s)
finished. total time: 0.015s
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn6Dn.png)</sup>

I have tried to use the Mi Unlock software, but when I enter my new Mi account and press the Unlock Now button, I get the following (what is covered was the ID of my old Mi account)

[image: Picture2]

I have tried to insert my SIM card, add the new account, activate the OEM unlock option, and try to unlock the bootloader using Fastboot, but I get what I indicated.